# Remove or customise "via @ShareThis" when adding ShareThis button dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, sharethis

I want to customise the "via @sharethis" part of the sharethis Twitter share button.

Everything I can find (http://blog.sharethis.com/2012/04/30/via-sharethis-is-here-2/ for example) says to add `st_via="TwitterUsername"` to the ShareThis span `<span class="st_twitter" st_via="TwitterUsername">…` however, I am dynamically adding the buttons so am unable to do this.

Here is how I create the buttons:

```
var defaults = {
            "service": "twitter",
            "element": …,
            … etc,
}

stWidget.addEntry(defaults);
```

How can I customise or remove the "via @ShareThis" part of the resulting twitter share button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boss, just add the st_via="[@theathere]" attribute to the span

```
<span id='twitter' class='twitter' st_via='[@theathere]'></span>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   var defaults = {
            "service": "twitter",
            "element": …,
            … etc,
   }

   stWidget.addEntry(defaults);

</script>
```

it will automatically add the st_via='' try it.

Comment: To remove the "via @ShareThis" I used ```st_via=""```.

Comment: all i had  to do is add a **space** in twitter handle and it should work
else if u need a **name** ... type in the **name** in the twitter handle ...and it should work ...